# Data loss when Python reads a 13mb file

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_txt(path):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        while file.readline():
            print(file.readline())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'data/data.html'
    get_txt(path)
```

This is my code, which prints the data of the source file line by line, and prints it on the console, but when I use Ctrl+F to search in the console, I don't find the data I want. It has read the data, but I don't know from which part it started reading, the data is missing

My file is an html file with a size of 13MB. The first line of data printed on the console is not:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

, but the data on the first line of my source file is this. The last line prints:

```html
</html>
```

this is reasonable. I've tried searching with Ctrl+F, but the results are always unexpected.

Comment: You should iterate over the `file` object line by line with a `for` statement: `for line in file: print(line)`

Answer (score 3):

```
    while file.readline():
        print(file.readline())
```

The `while` condition reads a line, and then the `print()` reads the next line and prints it.

You're only printing every other line.

Try this instead:

```
for line in file:
    print(line)
```

Comment: so what should i do @John Gordon

Answer (score 2):

presumably

```
def get_txt(path):
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
```

this will print every line in the file without skipping any... whereas before you would only print every other line

Comment: I've changed it, but it still doesn't work, why?

Comment: every line in that file will print with this method ... so if you are not finding it it is also not in your file... perhaps your input buffer scrolls it off screen in a way it is inaccessible (unlikely... but plausible)

Comment: If I don't use the loop, if I only call print(file.readline()) once, the console will output <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: that is irrelevant but is indeed the expected behavior ... (assuming that is the first line of the file(which is likely)) ... a likely explanation is that a 13MB file overflows your input buffer so the top is further back than you can scroll ... you could test this with `python my_script_thing.py | tee file2.test.html`  assuming you are on linux and then look and see what is in file2 ... it should be equivalent to the initial file

Comment: That's right, thank you very much for resolving my confusion

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author, to move the answer to the answers section)*.

The problem has been solved, and the configuration of the PyCharm/bin/idea.properties file has been modified: `idea.cycle.buffer.size=disabled`.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is slightly adjusted to work, you can replace the code you posted with this code and it should work as intended

```py
def get_txt(path_):
    with open(path_, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            print(line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'data/data.html'
    get_txt(path)
```

Comment: OK, thanks for your suggestion. The reason is as Joran Beasley said

Comment: `readlines()` is very inefficient, because it reads the whole file into memory at once.